# Instantiating Java class with getDeclaredConstructor raises IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, reflection, dynamic-programming, variadic-functions

I have class with `String[]` constructor (no default constructors):

I need to dynamically construct an instance by name:

```
package tests;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

interface I {

}

class A implements I {
    public A(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("Args = %s", args.toString());
    }
}

public class DynaCon {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Class<I> clz = (Class<I>) Class.forName("tests.A");
        Constructor<I> ctr = clz.getDeclaredConstructor(args.getClass());
        ctr.newInstance(args);
    }

}
```

Why is IllegalArgumentException raised?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem with varargs. Try:

```
I obj = ctr.newInstance(new Object[] { a });
```

`Constructor.newInstance` is defined as `T newInstance(Object... initargs)`. As `String[]` is an `Object[]` (and works prior to J2SE 5.0), you are trying to call a constructor with a single `String`-accepting argument.

Comment: That does not compile.  I updated my code above, pasted directly from a compiled java file.

Comment: You've changed the `a` variable to `args` in the question. Other than that, I don't know what the problem is. WHat compiler error do you get?

Comment: jdk 7.  I also tried I obj = ctr.newInstance((new Object[]) args), i.e a cast and that did not work.  The cast does work when I split it to two statements, the newInstance call fails.

Comment: Apparently I did have a typo somewhere which I cannot create now.  But this answer is correct.

Comment: @newacct Do you want to give any explanation with that comment?

Answer (score 2):

Tom Hawtin is correct that the string array is being expanded as the varargs arguments. The typical solution is to cast it to a non-array type:

```
I obj = ctr.newInstance((Object)a);
```